# Possible to find out what name servers domain is using from your internet /computer?

Tags: dns, nameservers

I changed my name servers for my domain name.

I can not tell if the domain name is using the 
old name servers or the new name servers.

because both name servers should work fine.

but i still would like to find out how my domain name 
is capable of being pointed to my server's IP address.

in other words.. which name server did it just use..

that is the question.

Answer (score 0):

In linux system,you can see the active name server using nslookup command 
like

## nslookup www.google.com